# how to create rectangles by getting scale values at the time in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to get the value of a scale and create rectangles as many as the value is. For example, if I adjust the scale to number 7, 7 rectangles would be created next to each other, and after that if I adjust the scale value to 3, the rectangles shown in the canvas decreases to three at that moment. I had used the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class rect:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.size = IntVar()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=800, height=300)
        self.scale = Scale(self.root, orient=HORIZONTAL, from_=3, to=20, tickinterval=1, variable=self.size)
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        x = 50
        y = 50
        for i in range(self.scale.get()):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 50, y + 50, fill='red')
            x += 50
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.scale.pack()


root = Tk()
a = rect(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I guess I have to use `trace` method, But I don't know how to.
Can anyone fix the code I used in the way which I explained.
Thank you.

Comment: do you want the screen to be refreshed as the scale is dragged? After it stops dragging? After the mouse button is released? How should the program know when to redraw the screen?

Comment: Yes.That's what I need. I want them to be refreshed after the scale gets dragged and the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to bind to `<ButtonRelease>`, and call your `show` method there. Since event bindings pass an object representing the event, you'll need to make that an optional argument if you also want to call `show` without any arguments.

For example:

```
class rect:
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.scale = Scale(...)
        self.scale.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.show)
```

I'm guessing you'll want to remove any previously drawn rectangles, so you'll need to call `delete` before creating the rectangles:

```
def show(...):
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    ...
```